# Java reports that the Java version is deprecated even though the latest version is installed

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, deprecated

Since I updated my Window version to Windows 10 an old Java programm doesn't start, instead I got a Java report that the Java version is deprecated. Now  I updated Java to the latest version but the error still occurs.

The Java programm was written with Java 4 and I'm using the latest Windows and Java version.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Any concrete error message? Maybe old Java API is either deprecated or removed that you used in your program.

Comment: Maybe the JavaSE wasn't installed or no environment variable? But without error, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a java in your system32 folder that may cause this issue.

You just press windows key and in the opening box type java.
The system will pick one java.exe, right-click the same and go to the path. If it is not your latest version, remove it.

You can verify the java version using the command java -version in command prompt.